# Selecting pictures in react native

Tags: react-native

I am using the react native camera roll function to retrieve videos from my phone's camera roll. I am able to get the videos to show up in a gallery in my app, but I can't seem to figure out how to make a button to open up this video and actually play it. Here is my code so far:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Image,
  FlatList,
  PermissionsAndroid,
  Platform,
} from 'react-native';
import CameraRoll from '@react-native-community/cameraroll';

class showVideo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: '',
    };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      const result = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        {
          title: 'Permission Explanation',
          message: 'ReactNativeForYou would like to access your photos!',
        },
      );
      if (result !== 'granted') {
        console.log('Access to pictures was denied');
        return;
      }
    }

    CameraRoll.getPhotos({
      first: 50,
      assetType: 'All',
    })
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({data: res.edges});
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.data}
          numColumns={3}
          renderItem={({item}) => (
            <Image
              style={{
                width: '33%',
                height: 150,
              }}
              source={{uri: item.node.image.uri}}
            />
          )}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default showVideo;
```

Any pointers or recommendations? All I have is a static overview of videos pulled from my camera roll in my app.

Answer (score 0):

I may suggest you to use `<TouchableHighlight />` added outside the `<Image/>` tag to catch when onPress. Is this what you want? It could know just press on image.

```
import { TouchableHighlight } from "react-native";
<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.functionToPlayVideo(item.node.image.uri)}>
   <Image
              style={{
                width: '33%',
                height: 150,
              }}
              source={{uri: item.node.image.uri}}
            />
</TouchableHighlight>
```